# What is the problem with my password change code? PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a password change form in php and mysql but I have problem. When I fill out the form and hit submit I got the empty error message. I'm really new in php and mysql and I don't find the problem. Here is the code detail from the public html/php:

```
                   <form action="passchange.php" method="POST">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="OldPass">Current password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="OldPass">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="NewPass">New password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="NewPass">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="NewPassAgain">Confirm new password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="NewPassAgain">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
                          I want to change my password
                          <span class="form-check-sign">
                              <span class="check"></span>
                          </span>
                      </label>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Change password</button>
                      <div id="warn">
                        <?php
                            if(@$_GET['EmptyChangePass']==true)
                            {
                        ?>
                             <div id="warn"><?php echo $_GET['EmptyChangePass'] ?></div>
                        <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?php
                            if(@$_GET['InvalidChangePass']==true)
                            {
                        ?>
                            <div id="warn"><?php echo $_GET['InvalidChangePass'] ?></div>
                        <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?php
                            if(@$_GET['ValidChangePass']==true)
                            {
                        ?>
                            <div id="warn"><?php echo $_GET['ValidChangePass'] ?></div>
                        <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                      </div>

                    </form>
```

And here is the passchange.php:

```
<?php

    $OldPass = $_POST['OldPass'];
    $NewPass = $_POST['NewPass'];
    $NewPassAgain = $_POST['NewPassAgain'];

    if(empty($_POST['OldPass']) || empty($_POST['NewPass']) || empty($_POST['NewPassAgain'])) {
        header("location:settings.php?EmptyChangePass=All fields are required");
    }
    else {
        if ($OldPass && $NewPass && $NewPassAgain) {
      require_once('connection.php');

      $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT pass FROM users WHERE user='$user'");
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryget);

      $OldPassDB = $row['pass'];
      if ($OldPass==$OldPassDB) {

        if ($NewPass==$NewPassAgain) {

          $update = "UPDATE users SET pass='$NewPass' WHERE user='$user'";
          $querychange = mysql_query($update);

          header("location:settings.php?ValidChangePass=Password changed");
        }
        else {
          header("location:settings.php?InvalidChangePass=Passwords are do not match");
        }
      }
      else {
        header("location:settings.php?InvalidChangePass=Passwords are do not match");
      }
        }
    }
?>
```

I tried to write some text with 'echo' after 'header' but It didn't write anything. Maybe my code is wrong? I have a registration form with the same 'if' starting and that is working.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You don't need `if ($OldPass && $NewPass && $NewPassAgain)` You already checked whether any of them were empty in the previous `if`.

Comment: You shouldn't be comparing the `$_GET` variables to `true`. They're strings, not booleans. You can use `isset()` to see which one is set, and then display that message.